# Imacro if else Statement personal code

Tags: imacros

i need to make this on imacro comannd

if found TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:invite to click this

else

to click this  TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:SeeMore

Comment: (-1) on the "Quality" of this Qt from me: FCI not mentioned, vague Description, still got 2 Quality Answers, and never any Follow-up from @OP... (And (+1) for both Answers...)

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple workaround:

```
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:invite
TAG POS=3 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:SeeMore
SET !ERRORIGNORE NO
SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 6
```

Answer (score 1):

I use Mozilla Firefox with JavaScript scripting Interface.
Copy this html below in index.html and open it with Firefox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<a href="https://www.google.com">invite</a><br>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/">Second link</a><br>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">SeeMore</a><br>

</body>
</html>
```

Save this code in click.js in Imacros:

```
if (iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:invite') == 1){
    iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:invite');
} else {
    iimPlayCode('TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:SeeMore');
}
```

Open index.html in Firefox and run click.js.
It should work as you need.

Runs OK with this: Firefox 35.0.1, iMacros for Firefox 8.9.7, Windows 7.